# SharePoint 2013 User Profile Service Application Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have created a User Profile Service Application and when i click on it it gives me error: "Sorry Something Went Wrong".

When i take the correlation Id check the ULS Logs, i found following errors/exceptions:

```
Failure retrieving application ID for User Profile Application Proxy 'User Profile Service Application': Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have e3d7b634-00ac-4825-9576-647d3042db34
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_AppID()

UserProfileServiceUserStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)

User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have e3d7b634-00ac-4825-9576-647d3042db34
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)

Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located at http://bil1010vrt:32843/e0e9f5dc277f466e8d6be27be3bfe327/ProfilePropertyService.svc is unavailable. This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
at [0]:

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()

at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)

UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsCompatibleDatabaseSchema(ProfilePropertyData propertyData)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache2.GetValueNow(K key)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()

Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ManageUserProfileServiceApplicationBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Please help me fixing this. I want the User Profile Sync to be working ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This error usually occurred in couple of ways. You should check following things.

- make sure user profile services is running on the server(bil101vrt)...you can check it from central admin>manage services on server> make user profile service is running
- try to reset Iis on the server.
- Stop and Start the User profile service from Central Admin.

Comment: user profie service is running and i did iisreset, no use :( :(

Comment: How many server in the farm?also try to browse this link http://bil1010vrt:32843/e0e9f5dc277f466e8d6be27be3bfe327/ProfilePropertyService.svc

Comment: One more thing, try to stop the User profile Service and start it from Central admin.

Comment: Also check if User Profile Sync Service is in running mode.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create My site host before provisioning User Profile Service Application?
Please follow this guide from Harbar to succesfully start and configure UPS: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx (this is for SP2010, but it is the same for sp2013 too).